# Bedeutung oder Synonym: "sowas kommt gut an"

Tags: meaning, phrase

Guten Abend,
habe ich richtig den Ausdruck "so was kommt gut an" verstanden? Heißt es ist popular, man mag es?
Danke für eure Antworte.
Marina

Answer (score 2):

Ja, das passt (so ungefähr).

Wenn man im Umgangssprachlichen feststellt, dass "etwas gut ankommt", dann stellt man fest, dass die Sache, ein Event oder Handlung einer oder mehrere anderen Personen oder Leuten allgemein gut gefällt, Zustimmung oder Anklang findet und / oder diese dabei Spass haben. Man kann sogar das 'gut' ohne allzuviel Bedeutungsverlust weglassen.

Man kann umgekehrt diesen Ausdruck statt mit 'gut' auch mit 'schlecht' bilden - was dann natürlich das Gegenteil bedeutet.

Siehe auch [DWDS Punkte 3 und 4](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ankommen)